# How can I send text or files securely between VirtualBox host and client and vice versa?

Tags: virtualbox

For security reasons, I would like to avoid using the clipboard or shared folders (to keeps things as compartmentalized as possible).

Comment: There is no way to do this. The act of sharing the data itself will always be a potential ingress point.

Answer (score 0):

What you’re asking for is something quite impossible, since you want to have security and share files between those “seperated” (compartmentalized) things. What if the file was infected? Please also consider [what is described here on the Information Security SE site](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3056/how-secure-are-virtual-machines-really-false-sense-of-security).

The probably simplest way is over a CloudService. Maybe something such as WeTransfer? But you could also host your own FTP/WebServer.